# How to convert ARGB to RGB and HEX?

Tags: c#

I have this function that takes cursor position color but i need to get ARG and HEX values

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));
}
System.Drawing.Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
label3.Text = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString();
Point p = new Point();
p.X = (this.Width / 2) - (label3.Width / 2);
p.Y = label3.Top;
label3.Location = p;
pictureBox1.BackColor = pixel;
rgbColor = pixel.ToString(); // I want this to be RGB and also HEX 
this.Invalidate();
```

Comment: `I want this to be RGB and also HEX ` - how do you expect this to be formatted? Have you looked at [the properties of `Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netframework-4.8#properties)?

Comment: Right now is like this (Color [A=255, R=235, G=156, B=43]) i need RGB like this 255, 255, 255 and HEX like this FF0000.

Comment: Wait, you want ARG - as in Alpha, Red, and Green? So your result here would be 255,235,156 and FFEB9C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use these two methods to get the Alpha/Red/Green combination you require:

```
public static string GetARG(Color c)
{
    return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", c.A, c.R, c.G);
}

public static string GetARGHex(Color c)
{
    return string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", c.A, c.R, c.G);
}
```

Usage:

```
string arg = GetARG(pixel); // 255,235,156
string argHex = GetARGHex(pixel); // FFEB9C
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FOL55057)

Answer (score 3):

Should be as easy as

**Extension method**

```
private static String ToRgbHex(this Color c) 
    => $"{c.R:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.B:X2}";
```

**Usage**

```
var myAweseomHexValue = pixel.ToRgbHex();
```

Comment: Probably because you didn't make it an extension. all good, ill leave it here anyway